# "printf" FORMAT: "Space" and "%-s\n"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell

I am learning shell scripts. There is a sample line that I can not understand in certain tutorial. Could anybody tell me the first line's meaning in the code below?

```
format="%8s%10s%10s   %-s\n"
printf "$format" "Dirs" "Files" "Blocks" "Directory"

total_dirs=$(find $HOME -type d | wc -l)
total_files=$(find $HOME -type f | wc -l)
total_blocks=$(du -s $HOME)

printf "$format" $total_dirs $total_files $total_blocks
```

My questions are about the fist line's second half.

1. About the usage of "space":

If there are 3 spaces between $3 and $4, the outputted line also has 3 space between $3 and $4?

2. About "%-s\n" part:

What is the meaning of "-(hyphen)" in this sample code?
I got same output result, even if I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash shell builtin inherits its format specifiers from the corresponding `C` routines, so often the most useful reference is `man 3 printf`. From there:

1. yes, any character that is not part of a format specifier is printed literally

> ```
>    Format of the format string
>        The format string is a character string, beginning and  ending  in  its
>        initial  shift state, if any.  The format string is composed of zero or
>        more  directives:  ordinary  characters  (not  %),  which  are   copied
>        unchanged  to the output stream; and conversion specifications, each of
>        which results in fetching zero or more subsequent arguments.  Each con‐
>        version specification is introduced by the character %, and ends with a
>        conversion specifier.  In between there may be (in this order) zero  or
>        more  flags, an optional minimum field width, an optional precision and
>        an optional length modifier.
> ```

2. it specifies that the value should be left-justified

> ```
>    -      The converted value is to be left adjusted on the  field  bound‐
>           ary.  (The default is right justification.)  The converted value
>           is padded on the right with blanks, rather than on the left with
>           blanks or zeros.  A - overrides a 0 if both are given.
> ```

Comment: The left/right justification is more obvious when that field has a width. Try `printf "%50s" "$total_blocks"` and `printf "%-50s" "$total_blocks"`

Comment: Thank you, steeldriver! I got that the hyphen's meaning is same like "%-50s".   "%-s\n", this part does not have any number, so I have thought it has different meaning!

Comment: Mr jackman, Thank you for commenting. I have tried your suggestion and confirmed that using "-" outputs different result. So, why is the sample code using "-"?  The part,"   %-s\n", includes no number, so I can not understand its necessity.